# \forloop problem(undefined control sequence)

Tags: pgffor, for-loop

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-bengali.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/devanagaridigits.sty)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/bengalidigits.sty))

Package polyglossia Warning: gloss-bengali.ldf is already loaded! on input line
 9.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf)
(./hallJimmaderListBlank.aux) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.22 \forloop
             {theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 20}{\hline}
?
```

Code

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
 \usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
%\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline \arabic{theyflines} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\rule{0cm}{0.4cm}}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{theyflines}
\begin{center}
fajajf
\end{center}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
A & B & C & D & E\\
\toprule
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 20}{\hline}\\
%\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 52}{\aline}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I don't find out the problem.

Comment: My bad for the documentclass ...
The command `\forloop` seems to be defined by the `forloop` package which you did not load.

Comment: @BambOo I also try loading `forloop` package but not works.

Comment: @alhelal Then please edit your MWE and provide the error with a loaded forloop package. But however, you are loading the pgffor package, which comes with `\foreach`command! See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5958641/1171221

Comment: The issue is that I (and maybe other users) cannot compile your document due to some specific fonts. Try to reproduce the error with a code that everyone should be able to compile so we can try to locate the error(s)

Comment: @BambOo I change the code for English language only.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkHz5.png

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get a different error once the `forloop` package is added:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.19 ...lines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 20}{\hline}
                                                  \\
```

This is the error that happens when you don't insert a tabular new line (`\\`) before horizontal rules (`\hline`, `\toprule`, etc.).

Your loop says:

```
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 20}{\hline}\\
```

or, more clearly,

```
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 20}{\hline}%
\\
```

which inserts 20 `\hline`s, then a `\\`, thus the `Misplaced \noalign` error.

To fix this, just move the `\\` *before* the `\hline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
%\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline \arabic{theyflines} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\rule{0cm}{0.4cm}}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{theyflines}
\begin{center}
fajajf
\end{center}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
A & B & C & D & E\\
\toprule
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 20}{\\ \hline}
%\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 52}{\aline}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]